# Start button 3 pixel offset in Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, desktop-customization

The "Start" button in my Windows 7 Professional is shifted three pixels upwards and to the left. Under it, another button is visible, but it seems to be an image and can't be clicked.

[image: taskbar showing the offset Start button]

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Your buttons look “unnaturally” small. Did you change some advanced theme settings?

Comment: Not that I know of. I did select Windows Classic theme, though. I also have "Show Small Icons" in Taskbar, but changing that setting only enlarges the buttons - the Start button is still 3px off.

Comment: Well from my quick comparison it appears you changed some font size. Perhaps via the DPI setting?

Comment: The DPI setting is at 125% (default). The font is Segoe UI and it also looks to be the default. I'm quite baffled :-(

Comment: Well so that would be the problem. Don’t use the classic theme with DPI scaling. Apparently, it doesn’t properly support it. In fact, just switch to Windows 10. It offers the latest in DPI scaling and IMHO the best.

Comment: No, the Classic theme did support DPI scaling. My theme somehow got corrupted. Thanks anyway, I really appreciated your support and I believe it got me thinking in the right direction; I hadn't tried changing themes or re-making one.

Answer (score 0):

So my theme is very basic and I remember only changing the background (a long time ago). *What the heck* I said, *I'll just whip up a new theme identical to the one before*.

And **it worked**.

So, if anyone has a similar problem, save the old theme, and make another.

But at that point I thought, *Chances are that @Daniel B is right: I must have made some change I don't remember. What can have I done?*. And since theme files are just text files, I opened the new and old .theme files in two copies of Notepad and -

*Wait.*

```
[Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics]

[Metrics]
NonclientMetrics=88 1 0 0  � � � � � �...
```

No wonder the theme malfunctions. It's a mystery how it was *working at all*; the file got somehow corrupted.

The SMART check, God bless, reports the hard disk as working properly and in full health. The `.theme` file appears to have been changed this afternoon, but it could have been me fiddling to understand the three-pixel mystery. The antivirus also reports everything OK.
Yesterday, the file was intact - I've just checked the backup, and tomorrow I'll run a diff between tonight's backup and yesterday's to check for other damages.